# Increase volume of song Logic Pro for iPad

Tags: logic-pro, mastering, volume

First of all apologies if this is a simple question but I haven’t found an answer anywhere.

I’ve just started using Logic Pro for iPad and my tracks are way too quiet. I have watched mastering tutorials etc and my tracks sound exactly how I want them to, but only with the device volume usually around 2-3 steps higher than for the vast majority of songs even when the master volume is as close to 0 as I dare. What can I do to get the volume up?

I am pretty new to mastering so please answer like I’m 10 :)

Comment: Hi Liam. There are a couple of similar questions on here. https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/25290/boost-volume-of-track-in-garageband https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/23324/final-mix-still-quiet-after-maxing-volume-and-compression Is there any reason these don't answer your question?

Comment: @n00dles I’ve tried them and they don’t work but I’m probably doing it wrong so I’ll keep trying. I’m already using compression and a limiter but if I turn them up any more the sound quality noticeably drops. Why doesn’t this happen when the device volume is turned up?

Comment: The device volume "turns up" the whole sound, equally.